# How can I block people getting onto the roof of the Nether in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm building a Minecraft "War" server where there are 2 teams. Each has a 750×750 area of the Nether to gain resources from. However, I don't want them getting onto the Nether roof and then breaking bedrock to gain access into the other team's side. I can use command blocks and commands.

Comment: I don’t exactly know the command for this, but you could just teleport anyone higher than 122 back to Y 122

Comment: Ok, if that's possible, then that would be perfect. I don't know the command, however.

Comment: Yes I know it is possible through accessing player NBT Position but I am not sure how to do it, I do not doubt that someone will soon see this who does, though. **However I might know, is the area you want finite or infinite (limited area or never ending area)?**

Comment: @Penguin It's probably finite. Question: *"2 teams. Each team has a 750x750 area."*

Comment: If you have access to commands, why not fill the nether ceiling with bedrock or barrier blocks? Then there is no easily accessible nether ceiling.

Comment: What version are you in?

Comment: @randomuser922 if a version is not specified one must assume the latest version

Comment: Yes, applolgies, I am in 1.16.4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit Player height in Minecraft 1.15.2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/371178/limit-player-height-in-minecraft-1-15-2)

Answer (score 4):

My method uses scoreboards for detecting position.  Since with scoreboards you can execute if a score is in a range.

**Note: This will work in a infinite area, and may cause less lag then some other methods**

**[*Hovering*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378413/how-can-i-block-people-getting-onto-the-roof-of-the-nether-in-minecraft) your mouse over italicized words will give you a short explanation/tooltip**

**Important: You must be in a Minecraft version of at least 1.13 for this method to work**

## Preparation

In Minecraft, you need to create a scoreboard objective with a dummy critera.  You can do that with the following command.

```
scoreboard objectives create ypos dummy
```

## After Preparation

Next, you need to have in a **Repeating Command Block** or a [***Ticking Function***](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378413/how-can-i-block-people-getting-onto-the-roof-of-the-nether-in-minecraft) a command that gets the [*`Pos[1]`*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378413/how-can-i-block-people-getting-onto-the-roof-of-the-nether-in-minecraft) of all players/entities and stores it in our `ypos` scoreboard.  The following command will accomplish that.

```
execute as @a at @s store result score @s ypos run data get entity @s Pos[1]
```

If you want it to work for all entities, replace [*`@a`*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378413/how-can-i-block-people-getting-onto-the-roof-of-the-nether-in-minecraft) with [*`@e`*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378413/how-can-i-block-people-getting-onto-the-roof-of-the-nether-in-minecraft).  Next, you need a **Repeating Command Block** or a [***Ticking Function***](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378413/how-can-i-block-people-getting-onto-the-roof-of-the-nether-in-minecraft) with a command testing for [*players*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378413/how-can-i-block-people-getting-onto-the-roof-of-the-nether-in-minecraft) that have a ypos score of [*122 or more*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378413/how-can-i-block-people-getting-onto-the-roof-of-the-nether-in-minecraft) and [*teleport them to 121 or lower*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378413/how-can-i-block-people-getting-onto-the-roof-of-the-nether-in-minecraft).  The following command accomplishes that.

```
execute as @a[scores={ypos=122..}] at @s run tp ~ 121 ~
```

Again, if you want this to work with entities, change the [*`@a`*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378413/how-can-i-block-people-getting-onto-the-roof-of-the-nether-in-minecraft) to [*`@e`*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378413/how-can-i-block-people-getting-onto-the-roof-of-the-nether-in-minecraft)

## Summary

This method stores the ypos of every player/entity in a scoreboard, then checks to see if the ypos value is greater than or equal to 122 and if so, it will teleport them down.

Comment: A user has reported that this may also take effect in other dimensions when they don't want it to. Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

**Note: The following method is for a finite area.**

## 1.13+

Command (obviously adjust the coordinates for your needs):

```
/execute as @a[x=0,y=123,z=0,dx=750,dy=200,dz=750] at @s run tp @s ~ 121 ~
```

- `x=0`..`y=`..`z=`... - Corner 1
- `dx=750`..`dy=`..`dz=`... - Corner 2
- `~ 121 ~` - Location of player, but at `Y` 121

## 1.8 - 1.12

Command (obviously adjust the coordinates for your needs):

```
/execute @a[x=0,y=123,z=0,dx=750,dy=200,dz=750] tp @s ~ 121 ~
```

- `x=0`..`y=`..`z=`... - Corner 1
- `dx=750`..`dy=`..`dz=`... - Corner 2
- `~ 121 ~` - Location of player, but at `Y` 121

## 1.7-

The selector arguments `dx`, `dy`, and `dz` did not exist pre-1.8.

Comment: There's no point in including answers for really old versions.

Comment: @pppery why not? It doesn’t take away from the post does it?

Comment: Suggestion: Combine this answer with an appropriately configured [world border](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/World_border) so that players cannot escape the finite area where they are intended to be.